# Google Now Swipe Icon

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am developing an application which is replacement of Google Now.
My application is already being launched when swiped up.

I need to replace icon of the ring?
Some application in market can do this and there is a feature in Cyanogenmod already. So it is possible, but how?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

After a few restarts it shows icon properly. I may need find a way to force it. Maybe i could restart SystemUI but how ? :)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".contact.ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Transparent">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_assist"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon" android:resource="@drawable/launch_button" />
```

Comment: It  works but takes a while and a few restart to make it work. :/